# método pegando valor errado

Tags: java, primefaces

Olha só, tenho esse botao em um datatable

```
<p:commandButton id="prepDownloadAditivoNovo" style="float:left;"
                        icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" value="Download" ajax="false"
                        actionListener="#{fileUploadBean.prepDownloadAditivoNovo}"
                        disabled="#{con.pdf}" >
                        <f:attribute name="codigo" value="#{con.id}" />
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileUploadBean.download}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

então lá no meu fileUploadBean.prepDownloadAditivoNovo eu recebo aquele código

só que eu preciso ordernar esse datatable por data, e uso um sortby no datatable

ele exibe tudo certinho, mas ao clicar no botao, em vez de ele passar o código que foi reordenado, ele passa o código na ordem original, como se não houvesse reordenação

alguem ja viu isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar o método 'prepDownloadAditivoNovo' passando o id por ele, sem usar o f:attribute, 

Ex: '#{fileUploadBean.prepDownloadAditivoNovo(con.id)}' e você pega o id no método feito.